# asp:listitem change content dynamically handle on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

All I have is an `asp:listitem` that is initially populated server side, but then depending on client selections I change its content, however when I try and get the selected value server side it is always null. I've tried `listbox.selectedvalue` and `Request.Form["nameofbox"]`, but nothing.

Comment: Please provide some code. I guess you are binding the asp:listitem control in Page_Load without the IsPostback check.

Comment: no I just have on the page asp:listbox which has default asp:listitems on the page. Then using javascript I change the values

Comment: Please provide the code of the asp:listbox and its related script.

Comment: your ok thanks this link seems to explain the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246992/listbox-changes-in-client-side-nit-appear-in-server-side-withen-asp-wizard-not-w

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp:hiddenfield control and populate it with the selected value from the client script. Then pull the hiddenfield value from the server-side event handler.

What kind of actions you are performing on the listbox control with the client script ?